# My Rpi 2 vnc doesn't run but puTTy is running after chmod u+s /bin/ping

Tags: vnc

[image]

I'm using vnc viewer on windows 8. They are connected by wifi module on the same lan. I've used this instruction to solve problem with an update.

I'm using Rpi 2 with Raspbian Jessie and VNC server 5.2.3. I could now access it by VNC "using vncserver :1 on putty" however VNC doesn't show desktop, it just shows grey screen with X cursor.

When I ping the RPi IP from windows, it can ping correctly.

[image]

Comment: I believe that question is very vague. Please elaborate more. Are you running vnc viewer on RPi  ? If yes, on which platform vnc server is running ? How are they connected ? etc etc. What made you chmod /bin/ping ?

Comment: What does ping have to do with putty? What distro/version are you using? Is there a firewall on either machine? Are both machines on the same network? Is the network a lan? can you ping from one machine to the other and vice versa? Are you connecting with a hostname or IP address? When you clarify what you mean ping me or vote to reopen.

Comment: I'm usong vnc viewer on windows 8 ....they are connected b y wifi module on the same lan  ... I've used this instruction to solve probpem with update

Comment: I'm using Rpi 2 with jessi .... vnc server 5.2.3 .... I could now access it by vnc however vnc doesn't show desktop it just show grey screen with X cursor

Comment: The grey screen with cursor is just the Xserver (display software) or equivalent running on the Windows VNC without an output from the "other end". For some reason (possibly the X security system - if there is one emulated in the VNC software - is probably not talking to its counterpart on the Pi).  Using putty (from the Windows machine) I'd try `export DISPLAY=`IP address of the Windows Machine`:0` so the Pi knows where to send the stuff it wants to show.  You might also consider installing [Cygwin](http://cygwin.com/) to help make your Windows more Unix-like...

Comment: These answers belong in the question not the comments. please edit your question. Also, explain what you mean by problem with update, is this why you ran chmod u+s /bin/ping and if so what was the specific problem.

Comment: You still have not answered the questions about ping and update issues. What did you do to get VNC to connect?

Comment: update failed .... I've used "vncserver :1" on putty

Comment: This is unanswerable - the state of your question is inconsistent with itself, for example you have something about ping but show output from apt-get...

Comment: I've change the images and edit my question to answer the questions.... 
this website allow me posting only 2 images..... 
no I don't have any thing about ping the raspberry ping correctly I've just answer the questions

Comment: For some reason the default window managers don't work with VNC (I'm still working on figuring it out). To get VNC working [use xfce4 instead](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-and-configure-vnc-on-ubuntu-16-04)